# No data returned from scraping rottentomatoes

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio, rotten-tomatoes

I cant figure out how to scrape the following data from https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/in-theaters/

```
Movie Title
Review Score
Release date
Link to movie details
Link to movie poster
```

I'm not getting back any data or entering my each loop.

[Rotten Tomatoes screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaXBS.jpg)

My code:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require("request");

// Make a request call to grab the HTML body from the site of your 
choice
request("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/in-theaters/", 
function(error, response, html) {

  // Load the HTML into cheerio and save it to a variable
 // '$' becomes a shorthand for cheerio's selector commands, much like 
 jQuery's '$'
 var $ = cheerio.load(html);

 // An empty array to save the data that we'll scrape
 var results = [];

 // Select each element in the HTML body from which you want 
 information.
  // NOTE: Cheerio selectors function similarly to jQuery's selectors,
  // but be sure to visit the package's npm page to see how it works
  $('mb-movie').each(function(i, element) {
    console.log("inside each");
    console.log($(element));
    var link = $(element).children().attr("href");
var title = $(element).find('h3').text();


// // Save these results in an object that we'll push into the results array we defined earlier
results.push({
  title: title,
  link: link
});

  });

 // Log the results once you've looped through each of the elements 
 found with cheerio
  console.log(results);
 });
```

Comment: can you format the code correctly pls

Comment: Just FYI, "Engage in the systematic retrieval of data or other content from the Services to create or compile, directly or indirectly, a collection, compilation, database or directory, without Fandango's prior written consent;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your selector is incorrect because it is missing the dot prefix for class names i.e. $(".mb-movie").

But even if you correct the selector, it still won't match anything because the movies are dynamically rendered on the page using JS after the page loads. You can test this by doing a "view source" on the page in browser and searching for the selector `mb-movie` - you'll not find any. The `mb-movie` elements are dynamically added by [media-browser.js](https://staticv2-4.rottentomatoes.com/static/dist/media-browser.js) which is executed as part of the page. Request is not a web-browser, it can only download the raw HTML.

RT used to have an API that seems to be no longer available. There is one from [fandango](https://developer.fandango.com/rotten_tomatoes) but I doubt you'll get what you need from it.

One other option could be to use a website automation library like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which run a headless browser to actually load the page and are programmable. See this part of the docs for more info: http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html#dom-manipulation

We don't know what you're doing this for, but note that RT's [terms of use](https://www.fandango.com/policies/terms-of-use) explicitly forbid retrieval for the purpose of creating a database of some sort. Thanks @DaveNewton

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!  I was just trying to so a small scraping project for a coding class using mongo and cheerio.  I'll find a new URL/site to use.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of investigation, i found that rottentomatoes actually loads the movies list over a rest api :

```
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/search/default-list
```

this should provid the data you need without having to go through a headless browser or anything at all !

Comment: Yes, the selector was wrong, but there are no mb-movie elements in the RAW HTML so this change won't fix the problem.

Comment: Actually there is, i just used chrome inspctor to check it out https://ibb.co/mBNnW7

Comment: As we've discussed in other comments, the chrome inspector shows you the DOM AFTER the Javascript in the page has run.  To see the HTML that `request()` will load, you have to do View/Source on the page and there are no `mb-movie` elements yet in that HTML.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are completely right, while investigating the network i found the api they actually use to load the data https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/search/default-list

it can be used to exctract all the data needed without having to go through a headless browser or anything!

Comment: Now, you just need to know if the OP has the right to use that API.  `/api/private` certainly raises questions about who is allowed to access that.

Answer (score 0):

The data you want is not available in the RAW HTML of the page which is all that cheerio can see.  You can see this yourself if you just load the URL into the browser and then do View/Source and look at the raw HTML.

If you look at that HTML, you will see an empty section:

```
<section class="mb-movies" style="opacity:1">
</section>
```

The data you're looking for is apparently added to the page via Javascript which is something that cheerio will not be able to see.  To see data in a page that is added via Javascript, you would have to use a headless browser engine such as PhantomJS.  Or, you can find a service on the web that offers an API to retrieve the data you want more directly.

In addition, your selector should have been `$('.mb-movie')` but the data isn't there so that won't work without running the Javascript in the page so that you can get access to the dynamically added data in the page.

Comment: it's just a mal formatted selector! and PhantomJS is maybe an overkill for this.

Comment: @tjadli - Did you look at the raw HTML?  I don't see any mb-movie items at all in the RAW HTML.  Yes, the selector was wrong, but the data isn't in the RAW HTML.

Comment: i actually checked the rawHTML and there's actually the div (mb-movies) that containes multiple mb-movie
https://ibb.co/iDjjB7

Comment: @tjadli - That's not the RAW HTML you're looking at.  That's the DOM inspector AFTER content has been added to the page with Javascript.  Do a View/Source on that page to see the RAW HTML that `request()` will have access to.

Comment: Yes yes you are right, i didn't notice that the html was loaded with request(), and i though cheerio takes the live html. i don't remember the name but there is a library that actually does that.

Comment: @tjadli - To get access to what Javascript adds to the page, you need a tool that sets up a whole browser environment and can run the page Javascript and then access the DOM.  That is commonly called a headless browser.  Cheerio just parses the RAW HTML.  It does not run Javascript in the page.